# Can a group act non-trivially on any set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Sorry, I know this is probably a very basic question but it's something I've been wondering about. I'm inclined to say no, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Can you clarify your quantifiers?  Are you universally or existentially quantifying the group and the set, and in what order?

Comment: @EricWofsey My bad. I am asking if the following is true: $\forall$ groups $G$ and $\forall$ sets $S$ there exists a group action of $G$ on $S$ (with possibly a small number of exceptions of groups and or sets).

Answer (score 4):

Consider the group $G=\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ and the set $X=\{0,1\}$. Neither $G$ nor the symmetric group $S(X)$ is a trivial group. Yet any action $G\to S(X)$ is trivial, because $S(X)$ doesn't have an element of order $3$.